# Specify java 1.8 JDK path in Spring boot pom.xml without setting java_home to 1.8 version

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

Hi I have a Multi module project in which I need to add a new Module which is a SPRING BOOT application. All the other modules run on java version 1.6 but I need to run the Spring boot module with java 1.8. Problem is that I cannot change the JAVA_HOME from 1.6 to 1.8. I need to specify Java location in POM.xml of Spring boot Application.

I tried to provide the JDK path to the compiler and version in the POM.xml but I get error Unsupported major minor issue  like this :

```
**org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:494)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/plugins/clean/CleanMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)**
```

This is the POM that I am using.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
     4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.data.service.risk</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DataService</name>
    <description>Data service Project</description>
    
    <properties>
    <jdk.version>8</jdk.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jdk>C:\software\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_121</jdk>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- this is a java 6 compiled dependency-->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.data.risk</groupId>
    <artifactId>java_6_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.19</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
    </dependencies>
    
    
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <jvm>C:\software\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java</jvm>
    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <executable>C:\software\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac</executable>
    <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>    
    </project>
```

Please let me know how I can specify the JDK location inside the POM.xml without setting JAVA_HOME to java 1.8 for Spring Boot Application

Answer (score 2):

Try adding version as 3.8.1 as below

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

For more help
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/java-compiler.html

Comment: Hi I already tried this but getting same error. Problem is my JAVA_HOME points to java version 1.6. I need java 8 only for this particular project and I cannot change the JAVA_HOME to 1.8

Answer (score 2):

That's simple. Try adding the following property to pom.xml.
Note that I added java 11 . you can add the version you need.

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Also add the following plugin specifying your JDK path. For example :
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\javac

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
      <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

---

After adding the above code my spring boot project was working as expected.
Ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html